# 配列の中の値を1つずつ減らすにはどのようにすればいいのか？

Tags: php

ある連想配列があり、`value` = 整数型が入っています。
この値を特定の `Key` の順番ごとに減らしていきたのですが、カッコ悪くない実装方法や効率的な方法があったら教えてください。

**コード：**

```
$array = ['banana'=>3, 'orange'=>2, 'apple'=>2];

//banana -> orange -> apple の順に減らしたい。

$subtraction　 = 3;//減らす数

for($i = 0; $i < $subtraction ; $i++ )
{
    if ($array['banana'] > 0 && ($i === 0 ||$i === 3 ||$i === 6  )) {$array['banana']--; continue;}
    if ($array['orange'] > 0 && ($i === 1 ||$i === 4  )) {$array['orange']--;continue;}
    if ($array['apple']  > 0 && ($i === 2 ||$i === 5  )) {$array['apple']--;continue;}
}
```

Comment: 対象が仮に「連想配列の中身すべて」であるなら、「特定の key の順番ごと」である必要は無さそうですが、この条件はなにか理由がありますか？

Comment: わかりづらくてすみません。　$subtraction　 = 3;//減らす数　が一定ではなく
//banana -> orange -> apple の順に減らすのが仕様なので、「特定の key の順番ごと」と書きました。
最終的な結果が同じなら、どのkeyから減らしても大丈夫です。

Comment: 掲示されているコードでは、`$array = ['banana'=>2, 'orange'=>3, 'apple'=>2];` と `$subtraction = 7;` の場合は `['banana'=>0, 'orange'=>1, 'apple'=>0]` になりますが、これは想定される結果ですか？ `['banana'=>0, 'orange'=>0, 'apple'=>0]` になるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> banana -> orange -> apple の順に減らす

の分岐条件を単純にして見ました。
**$i_mod = $i % count($array);** は、定義された配列要素の数での余りを得ています。

```
$array = ['banana'=>3, 'orange'=>2, 'apple'=>2];

//banana -> orange -> apple の順に減らしたい。
//順番を変える時は$arrayの登録順番を変える

$subtraction = 3;//減らす数

$array_key = [];//番号でアクセスできるように配列を作る。
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  $array_key[] = $key;
}

for($i = 0; $i < $subtraction; $i++ )
{
  $i_mod = $i % count($array); //$i % 3
  $key = $array_key[$i_mod];
  if ($array[$key] > 0) {
    $array[$key]--;
  }
}
```

*カッコ悪と思うのは理解せずに作成しているからと思うのですが*

Answer (score 1):

コメントにも書きましたが、掲示されているコードでは配列の値が `0` の場合は decrement しないのに `$subtraction` の値が decrement されています。
以下は、配列の値が `0` の場合は `$subtraction` の値をそのままにする、という仕様を前提としています。

```php
<?php

$array = ['banana'=>2, 'orange'=>1, 'apple'=>6];
$order = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple']; // 減らす順序
$subtraction = 7; // 減らす数

$subtraction = min($subtraction, array_sum($array));
$len = count($order);
for($i=0;$subtraction;$i=(++$i)%$len) {
    if ($array[$order[$i]] > 0) {
        $array[$order[$i]]--;
        $subtraction--;
    }
}

print_r($array);

//
// Array
// (
//     [banana] => 0
//     [orange] => 0
//     [apple] => 2
// )
```